# Django creating model with foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have models like following:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    what_task = models.CharField(max_length=100, )

    #This helps to print in admin interface
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.what_task)


class Step(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='steps', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    what_step = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, )

    #This helps to print in admin interface
    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % (self.what_step)
```

I have serializers:

```
class StepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Step
        fields = '__all__'

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    steps = StepSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        steps_data = validated_data.pop('steps')
        task = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for step_data in steps_data:
            Step.objects.create(task=task, **step_data)
        return task
```

and my views:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def task_list(request):
    """
    List all tasks, or create a new task.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        tasks = Task.objects.all()
        serializer = TaskSerializer(tasks, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am expecting that when I create a Task, I also create it's Steps in a single request. My request JSON sent from frontend looks like following:

```
{what_task: "Sample task three", steps:[{task: 0, what_step: "Test Step"}]}
```

This throws me `{"steps":[{"task":["This field is required."]}]}` error. What am I doing wrong? Am I sending wrong JSON?

**P.S.**: As I do not have a task id at the time of creation, I was sending 0, what should be correct value, how am I suppose to handle it on backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StepSerializer` is expecting to receive a `Task` id. In your situation, it is not required as you grab it from the parent serializer (`TaskSerializer`).

Just modify your `StepSerializer` to [exclude](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include) the task field:

```
class StepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Step
        exclude = ('task',)
```

You may also set that field as [`read_only`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields) if you want to display but it should not be necessary as it is included in the `Task`.

In any case you may omit the `task` field in `steps` when creating the task (any value you set will be ignored anyway).